# How to fetch more than 1000 images with the Reddit API?

Tags: python, web-scraping, reddit

I've written a Reddit image scraper and the Reddit API is only letting me go up to the latest 1000 images. Does anyone know if I can pay extra to get more data (to go into the hundred thousands), or a free workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

> the reddit API is only letting me go up to the latest 1000 images

I assume you mean the listing only goes back 1000 submissions. That is a hard limit that applies to all reddit listings except for http://www.reddit.com/new (as far as I know). At the present time there is no option to pay for *extra* API access. However, assuming you obey [reddit's API rules](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API), you can use the http://www.reddit.com/new listing to go back as far as you want and simply filter out submissions to subreddits you don't care about.

Here's a simple [PRAW](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw) example that counts the number of submissions made to a set of subreddits in the last 10000 submissions (it takes approximately 200 seconds to run).

```
import praw
r = praw.Reddit('stackoverflow question test')
subs = set(['aww', 'funny'])

count = 0
for submission in r.get_new(limit=10000):
    if submission.subreddit.display_name.lower() in subs:
        count += 1
print(count)
```